# Updating a nested data structure using lenses

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

I'm currently trying to make parts of my code more concise using lenses. In particular, I have a [HTTP Request](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.7.2.1/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#t:Request) where I want to replace the value of a header with the name `Private-Header`.

I managed to write the function that updates the `RequestHeaders`:

```hs
updateHeaders :: RequestHeaders -> RequestHeaders
updateHeaders headers = headers & traverse . filtered (\header -> fst header == "Private-Header") %~ set _2 "xxxxxx"
```

However, I'm struggling with coming up with a function that extracts the headers from a requests and updates them. Without lenses, it could look like this:

```hs
updateRequest :: Request -> Request
updateRequest req = req {requestHeaders = updateHeaders (requestHeaders req)}
```

Is there a way to implement this function using lenses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly.  First, you need an optic that represents the value of the `"Private-Header"` header within a `RequestHeaders` object.  A reasonable candidate is a traversal, which allows zero or more occurrences of one type within another.  (Typically, you'd only have zero or one private headers, but there's nothing fundamental about the `RequestHeader` type that prevents two or more headers with the same name, so a traversal seems the safest bet.)

The appropriate type for this optic is:

```
privateHeader :: Traversal' RequestHeaders ByteString
```

You've already done most of the work for defining this optic in `updateHeaders`, you just need to rearrange the parts.  The expression:

```
traverse . filtered (\header -> fst header == "Private-Header")
```

is an optic that pulls out matching `Header` values from the `RequestHeader`.  It's a valid traversal as long as you don't use it to modify the keys and break the filtering, so we can compose it directly with the lens `_2` to create a new traversal that extracts the header values from `type Header = (ByteString, ByteString)`:

```
privateHeader = traverse . filtered (\header -> fst header == "Private-Header") . _2
```

By the way, this new traversal allows us to simplify the implementation of `updateHeaders`, too.

```
updateHeaders :: RequestHeaders -> RequestHeaders
updateHeaders = set privateHeader "xxxxxx"
```

Second, we need an optic that represents the value of the `RequestHeaders` fields of a `Request`.  You can build one with the `lens` function:

```
headers :: Lens' Request RequestHeaders
headers = lens getter setter
  where getter = requestHeaders
        setter req hdrs = req { requestHeaders = hdrs }
```

Now, you can compose `headers` and `privateHeaders` to create a new traversal:

```
privateHeaderInRequest :: Traversal' Request ByteString
privateHeaderInRequest = headers . privateHeader
```

and `updateRequest` can be implemented as:

```
updateRequest :: Request -> Request
updateRequest = set (headers . privateHeader) "xxxxxx"
```

Full code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Lens
import Network.HTTP.Client
import Network.HTTP.Types
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)

privateHeader :: Traversal' RequestHeaders ByteString
privateHeader = traverse . filtered (\header -> fst header == "Private-Header") . _2

updateHeaders :: RequestHeaders -> RequestHeaders
updateHeaders = set privateHeader "xxxxxx"

headers :: Lens' Request RequestHeaders
headers = lens getter setter
  where getter = requestHeaders
        setter req hdrs = req { requestHeaders = hdrs }

updateRequest :: Request -> Request
updateRequest = set (headers . privateHeader) "xxxxxx"

main = do
  request <- parseRequest "http://localhost:8888/"
  -- could use "headers" lens to set this, but let's do it manually
  -- for clarity...
  let request' = request { requestHeaders = [("Private-Header","hello"),
                                             ("Other-Header","goodbye")] }
  print $ requestHeaders (updateRequest request')
```

Comment: Ok so the main point I missed was that I construct a single optic that points to the field I want to update and in the end I call `set` on it once. Btw, the header names are case insensitive, so it automatically does a case-insensitive match

Comment: Oh, you're right.  I've deleted the comment about doing a case insensitive match.